# Is Sculpt Spell feature a Evocation School exclusive to avoid hitting allies?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, feats

If I cast Stinking Cloud, or Grease, or any other Battlefield Control spell under the Sculpt Spell feat, would it work in order to "create holes" and not hit my allies, or it is exclusive to Evocation spells?

Comment: *D&D* 3.5 I assume (and did for the edit)? It isn't much of an assumption, but it's always nice to have it super clearly.

Comment: Please note for future reference that you need to mention the *game* as well as the edition. 3.5 doesn't clarify things if we don't know what game you're talking about.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Sculpt Spell doesn't list any restriction on which schools of magic it can be used on, only that it applies to "an area spell." *Grease* has an Area entry in its description, so there's no reason why it wouldn't be able to benefit from the feat.

*Stinking cloud*, however, is more of a gray area. By a natural English reading, it's clearly a spell that affects an area. But in its description it doesn't have an Area, but rather an Effect. So by RAW, it doesn't work with the feat, but logically it makes enough sense, and for the cost of a feat and a higher level spell slot I don't think it would be broken to allow it to work (at least not more broken than such spells already tend to be).